Layout cast exception TableWrapLayout v GridLayout
Issue i am getting java.lang.classcastexception: class org.eclipse.swt.layout.griddata cannot be cast to class org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets.tablewrapdata. Why?
//Note this code is incomplete
ScrolledForm form;
FormToolkit toolkit;

createFormContent(IManagedForm managedForm) {
 form = managedForm.getForm();
 toolkit = getFormEditor().getToolkit();
    
   
    TableWrapLayout formLayout = new TableWrapLayout();
    formLayout.numColumns = 1;
    form.getBody().setLayout(formLayout);
       
        
    createControls(form.getBody()); 
}
private void createControls(Composite composite) {
    this.composite = composite;
    Label headerLabel = new Label(composite, SWT.NONE);
    if (isEditable()) headerLabel.setText("Table Heading");
    else headerLabel.setText("Table Heading - View Mode");
  
    if (isEditable()) {
    // This area does not complain about the casting of TableData v GridData
   Composite linkGroup = toolkit.createComposite(composite);
   GridLayout linkLayout = new GridLayout();
   linkLayout.numColumns = 2;
   linkGroup.setLayout(linkLayout);
ImageHyperlink saveLink = 
   toolkit.createImageHyperlink(linkGroup, SWT.NONE);
         saveLink.setText("Save and close");
ImageHyperlink refreshLink = 
            toolkit.createImageHyperlink(linkGroup, SWT.NONE);
         refreshLink.setText("Refresh");
}
    //think its this section that complains about the casting
    Composite tableSectionComp = toolkit.createComposite(composite);
    GridLayout gridLayout = new GridLayout();
    gridLayout.numColumns = 1;
    tableSectionComp.setLayout(gridLayout);
    gridLayout.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL_BOTH));
     
    getTableData(tableSectionComp);
    }

 is it simply you can mix and match org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets.TableWrapLayout with org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout?
Regards, JemRug

All that is required is that the layout data of a control must match the layout of the parent composite. GridData if the layout is GridLayout, TableWrapData if the layout is TableWrapLayout.
